# Error Not Found app.js - in node.js webscraper

Tags: node.js

I just started learning node.js and following the webscraper example in [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js/). After I typed "npm start" in the terminal and visited localhost:8081/scrape. I got this error message. I'm sure this file directory is correct.

> Error: Not Found
> at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Node.JS\webscraper\app.js:35:13

File tree:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ4DI.jpg)

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "webscraper",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
    "request": "latest",
    "cheerio": "latest"
  }
}
```

After I deleted the following code generated by express in app.js, it works! May I ask why?

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Comment: Could you post your package.json file and your file tree?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added package.json and file tree generated with "dir-tree-creator".

Comment: Thanks, i have some problem understanding your problem , can you tell me if you followed exactly the tutorial you linked ? what is in your app.js file? and in your index.js file?

Comment: Or you can just type node app.js or/and node index.js in your terminal and tell what is happening